# Why is the move(&&) called instead of const &?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

These are the definition of Same function, but the first is passed the parameter using `move(&&)` and the second is passed using (`const &`).

```
template<typename T, class Allocator>
void MyList<T, Allocator>::push_front(T && t)
{
    Link<T>* newnode = new Link<T>(t);

    if (empty()) {
        head = std::move(newnode);
        tail = std::move(newnode);
        std::cout << "Linked List Created using move with value: " <<t<< std::endl;
    }
    else {
        head->prev = std::move(newnode);
        newnode->next = std::move(head);
        head = std::move(newnode);
        std::cout << "Node Inserted using move at the beginning of List with value: " <<t<< std::endl;
    }
}

template<typename T, class Allocator>
void MyList<T, Allocator>::push_front(const T & t)
{   Link<T>* newnode = new Link<T>(t);
    if (empty()) {
        head = newnode;
        tail = newnode;
        std::cout << "Linked List Created with value: "  <<t<< std::endl;
    }
    else {
        head->prev = newnode;
        newnode->next = head;
        head = newnode;
        std::cout << "Node Inserted at the beginning of List with value: " <<t<< std::endl;
    }
}
```

when I run the below code in main:

```
 MyList<int> l1;
    l1.push_front(5);
    l1.push_front(std::move(8));
```

I always get the `cout` of the `move` function. Shouldn't the `const &` be the default one?

Comment: `std::move(new Link<T>(t))` wtf this suppose to do? other moves?

Comment: @Slava Yea your right, I was adding move every where, I was going to modifying it but I forgot. Thanks for the heads up!!

Comment: Programming does not work by guessing, you should understand what you are doing instead of blindly put move everywhere

Comment: note that `std::move` does not move anything, it is a value category cast

Comment: You should read this first https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers

Comment: @Slava: Universal references are based critically on type deduction. Since all template parameters in this example are **class** template parameters, universal references are not really relevant in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`5` is in itself an rvalue. It's a temporary value that's only used for `push_front` so the compiler can safely make the `&&` call. To see the expected behaviour, try an lvalue:

```
 MyList<int> l1;
 int foo = 5;
 l1.push_front(foo);
 l1.push_front(std::move(foo));
```

The compiler can't be sure you won't be using `foo` after the first call and thus has to call `const &`.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect with lvalue first function will be called as well.